# Confused about index in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm confused about the index in python. This is my problem:

```
number = "1234567"
print(number[-3:1:-3])
```

Output: 5

Why did the output is only 5 and not 52? When the starting position is in the number 5 and the end position is in the number 1(Am I right?). From the right(SINCE IT IS NEGATIVE SO REVERSE) i count from 5 then skipped 2 spaces then the number 2 should also be included.

Comment: `[-3:1:-1]` outputs `543`, if that's any hint…

Answer (score 2):

In the notation `a:b:c`, `b` is not included. So to achieve your desired output you should use:

```
print(number[-3:0:-3])
```

Comment: Is it always b is not included during the a:b:c notation?

Comment: you can try it yourself and see how it works, remembering that -1 is the last element of the array :) what does `print(number[0:-1])` return? what about `print(number[0:-2])`? See how the last one is not included?